# Does tinycore's \ PiCore's Python limits prevent Python library installation for controlling a relay board?

Tags: python, python3, tinycore

On Raspbian: I have successfully implemented instructions per: https://github.com/SequentMicrosystems/megaio-rpi

```
 git clone newbielink:https://github.com/SequentMicrosystems/megaio-rpi.git [nonactive]
 cd megaio-rpi/
 ~/megaio-rpi$ sudo make install
```

All Mega-IO card functions are available through the "megaio" command. If you clone the repository, any update can be made with the following commands:

~$ cd megaio-rpi/ 
~/megaio-rpi$ git pull
~/megaio-rpi$ sudo make install

For python library install and usage checkout the "python" subfolder.z

## QUESTIONS

I have installed python3.6 on PiCore 9.3, which has a very different paradigm form a traditional SSD based computer: "[frugal install](http://tinycorelinux.net/concepts.html)".   I am trying to understand:

- Can I can use vendor provided python libraries on PiCore?
- After copying the `megaio-rpi` directory from the Raspbian instance to picore what would be next steps?

Any examples (URLS \ Videos) are appreciated.  It is not clear to me what the Google keywords would be to return such videos / examples (assuming they exist).

Answer (score 0):

All tests performed on a rpi-Zero-W + picore 9.0.3

## Install the python3.6 Tiny Core extension (.tcz):

```
tce-load -wi python3.6.tcz
```

## Install pip3:

```
mkdir cd /home/tc/pip3Persistent
cd /home/tc/pip3Persistent
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo -H python3.6 get-pip.py
```

Save the 4 new directories to ensure persistence:

```
vi /opt/.filetool.lst

usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/  #pip3 verified
usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-20.0.2.dist-info/ #pip3 verified  
usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wheel/  #pip3 verified
usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wheel-0.34.2.dist-info/ #pip3 verified
```

Commit persistent save:

```
filetool.sh -b
```

Verify pip3:

```
sudo -H pip3 install pip-install-test
python3.6 -c 'import pip_install_test'
```

Reboot and re-verify to prove persistence